# ref callback is being applied to first matching class

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component that has a render like this:

```
render: function(){
        return (
            <textarea className="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" ref={this.initiatePagedown}></textarea>
        )
}

initiatePagedown: function(input){
         //code that initiates markdown editor.
         attr = $(input).attr('id').split('wmd-input')[1];
        converter = new Markdown.Converter();
        Markdown.Extra.init(converter, {highlighter: "highlight"});
        editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, attr);
        return editor.run();    
    },
```

The component mounts n different times, hence creating multiple textareas.

The problem is the ref callback is running with the input of the first component, so it's always the first component that's manipulated, not the one that I select. So let's say this component was mounted twice, then the ref callback will be called on the first component instance twice, not once of each component instance. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: When do you want to do the manipulation? onChange. onBlur, etc?

Comment: What kind of manipulation?

Comment: it involves initiating a markdown editor for this specific textarea.

Comment: I cannot reproduce.... All the text areas are acting individually..
https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/3Lm4sbaL/1/

Comment: @PraneshRavi i updated my question with exactly what the manipulation is, please check now, thank you.

Comment: Which wmd editor are you trying this with? Just thinking i'd be down to the editor library.

Comment: @zv.diego I am using pagedown, check my updated question please.

Comment: @AhmadAl-kheat Then, `initiatePagedown` will be called for all the `n` textareas. that not what you wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Pagedown editor to point to a specific element ID on the page, because you're passing in the second argument, `attr`:

```
new Markdown.Editor(converter, attr);
```

Check out [the documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/wikis/PageDown.wiki) for the second argument of the `Markdown.Editor` constructor:

> If given, this argument is a string, appended to the HTML element ids of the three elements used by the editor...so you may create the second input box as `<textarea id="wmd-input-2">` and pass the string "-2" as the second argument to the constructor.

Right now you're always creating an editor with the same ID:

```
id="wmd-input"
```

So the editor constructor will always match every existing instance of that ID on the page.

This is a very poor API forcing you to point to element IDs. As a workaround I would probably make the id a prop you pass in, so that the wrapping component/page can decide how many editors should be there, and you can build the ID like this

```
return (
    <textarea id={ `wmd-input-${ this.props.id }` } ... />
)
```

Then you can instantiate the unfortunate API with something like

```
editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, `-${ this.props.id }`);
```

Comment: I've just created a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/notamoc/2/edit?js,output) with the above changes to demonstrate what @AndyRay said, that you need a unique id for every markdown instance you could like to spawn.